# sticky menu in FIREFOX wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So can you go to [www.natropiegra.pl](http://www.natropiegra.pl) in at least 2 browsers.

In Google Chrome and Opera it's all good but in Firefox my menu is not exactly at the top of the site. There's a slight shift down.
But only the background part with list `ul`

Why?

Here's code.

CSS:

```
    .nav-container { 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif; 
    background: #1a1a1a repeat-x 0 0; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    
}
    

.f-nav { 
    z-index: 901; 
    position: fixed; 
    left: 0; 
    top: -70; 
    width: 100%; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888;

} 
    
.nav { height: 102px; }
    .nav ul { list-style: none; }
    .nav ul li{float: left; margin-top: 50px; padding: 15px; border-right: 0px solid 

#e0e0e0;}
    .nav ul li:first-child{ padding-left: 31.0em;}
    .nav ul li a { text-decoration: none; color: #e0e0e0 }
    .nav ul li a:hover{ text-decoration: none; color: #00bca4;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="nav-container">
<div class="nav">

<div id="up2">
<a href="#logowhite1"><img id="up1" src="./image/up.png" alt="">
</a>
</div>

<div id="yt">
<a href="http://www.youtube.pl/user/natropie" target="_blank"></a>
</div>

<div id="fb">
<a href="http://www.facebook.pl/natropiegra" target="_blank"></a>
</div>



 <ul>
        <li><a href="#pasek1">INFO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pasek2">ZASADY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pasek3">GRAJ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pasek4">PREZENTY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pasek5">KONTAKT</a></li>
 </ul>
    <div class="clear"></div> 

</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.localScroll();
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("document").ready(function($){
    
    var nav = $('.nav-container');
    navOff  = nav.offset();
    
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 49) {
            nav.addClass("f-nav");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("f-nav");
        }
    });
 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list has a default margin that shifts your header. This should fix it:

```
.nav ul {
     margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the top of your CSS file and this issue will disappear:

```
* {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: you mean to the css of menu? 
it didn't disappear ;(

Comment: No, I mean to the CSS file. So copy it exactly and throw it into your CSS file or as the first line in your <style> tag.

Comment: @Mac - check Laurent le Beau-Martin answer. It does the trick.

Comment: I disagree with Laurent le Beau-Martin. You should be doing it the ACTUAL way it's supposed to be done, and that is to use the universal selector to remove all default margins and paddings.

I've already verified that using the universal selector fixes this problem.

Comment: @JoshuaWalcher I disagree. What if you want to have the default margin and padding for other elements (including other lists), but not for the menu in question? While your answer may work, The selected answer is the most correct in terms of the scope of the question.

Comment: From a production environment standpoint for enterprise-level code (i.e. that lots of people in lots of browsers will be viewing my pages), I wouldn't want to work with default margins and paddings. I would want to set them myself so that browser defaults don't screw with the design. Targeting specific elements after the fact on a browser-by-browser level rather than starting from an equal baseline is sloppy, and I stand by my statement.